# Can I influence the file size (FBX) with length and complexity of my animation?

Tags: animation, rigging, export, polycount, .fbx

Is there a way how to reduze file size (FBX export) with length and complexity of my animation?

I'm working on a 3D character and will implement the Rigg soon. I'm curios about the file size because it have to be a maximum of 3,5MB in total (with 3d geometry, textures and animation).
Is there a way how to control animation file size? Is there a specific value how much file size one single animation need (~10 sec long).  I need to export 8 animation in total.

Thank you very much for your help°!

Comment: images are the big space takers, multitudinous vertices being second. Animations would take up more if there are like a whole lot of key frames.

Comment: In the exporting window you can increase the simplifing and the sampling rate to decrease the filesize a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints!!! 
I guess I will go with 20.000 Tris and a maximum of 1-2 2k Textures and hope this is good enough to spare some file size :)